# Does "rsync -a" command saves all the attributes of source files?

Tags: rsync

I'd photos and videos on my android phone. I took back up of them in my HDD.
I wanted to keep the attributes of the files as it is as you can understand the importance of that. Main attributes to save are date, time, location (if it is there in the source files).

For achieving this, I ran

```
rsync -a "source dir" "dest. dir"
```

Destination contains all the folder structure of the source and the files were also having the same date and time. So, it seems it has worked properly. But I haven't checked if location also got saved if the source file had location (place where video/audio was taken).

So, just would like to get a clarification that this command has saved all the attributes? Also is there any other options to `rsync` that can be used for more clarity on attributes or for the getting the job done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location (from GPS) is, from the perspective of the filesystem, part of the file's data, not its metadata. It's stored in the EXIF, XMP, etc. tags inside the file.

So `rsync` (or even plain `cp`) will preserve it.

There are a bunch of tools that can show EXIF and XMP data in a file; for example:

```
$ exiv2 -pa pr IMG_20150530_155931.jpg
Exif.Image.DateTime                          Ascii      20  2015:05:30 15:59:31
Exif.Image.GPSTag                            Long        1  543
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSDateStamp                    Ascii      11  2015:05:30
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSAltitudeRef                  Byte        1  Above sea level
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef                 Ascii       2  West
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSImgDirection                 Rational    1  29/1
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude                    Rational    3  77deg …
⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

"Location (place where video/audio was taken)" as you describe it is
not, in general, metadata as far as file systems are concerned: it is
data; part of the file's content, rather than an attribute external to
it.

So, if your files were copied correctly, which you checked, then the
"location data" will have been copied as well. This would be true
even if you had copied using a tool other than rsync.

The only way that such image or video metadata, stored within the
file, would be stripped, is if you had converted using a content-aware
tool (e.g., to resize your pictures or videos) instead of just copying.